# How to add cocoa pods to a Framework project

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have an application project which includes a framework project, like this:

```
App
  myKit.xcodeproj
  App
  Products
   ....
```

I added a cocoa pod to the myKit project and opening myKit.xcworkspace the framework compiles without any error.

Opening App project though, I get an error in the framework code which cannot import the cocoa pod library:

```
import UIKit
import ....
import Library <- CANNOT IMPORT THIS

public class MyKit: ... {
   ...
}
```

the error is:

> No such module 'Library'

I followed various suggestions between them also adding a pod and a podspec files to the App project but nothing worked.

Can anyone suggest me the right way to sort this issue out?